# 'Unless' in hypothetical constructions

Tags: conditionals, unless

I have been told that 'unless' can't be used in hypothetical clauses as follows:

Unless Ann had studied hard, she would have failed the exam.

My question is, why is using 'unless' in the conditional clause above unacceptable?

Comment: Unlike *if* constructions, you can't use it if you *know* whether or not she failed her exams. But if you don't know, it's fine.

Comment: There may be some quirky usage rules that apply to *unless*, but that one isn't one of them.

Comment: But you can say "Unless Ann studies hard, she will fail her exam".

Comment: I think they are probably confused with not using *will* or *would* in the clause following *unless* (the subordinate one). It is fine in the main clause. See here [unless](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/unless)

Comment: @Kate Bunting: l know that it's ok to use it in present and past simple conditional clauses. But l was wondering why it's unacceptable in past perfect conditional clauses.

Comment: @Phil Sweet: l don't think Quirk 1985 uses quirky rules. He mentioned that using 'unless' with past perfect tense in a a conditional subclause is not widely accepted. But he didn't give any details.

Comment: We are again in that territory of a usage that strikes native speakers as a bit odd (is that the same thing as 'not widely accepted'?) but where one can't put one's finger on the precise error, if indeed there is one. It feels much more natural to say :'If Ann had not studied hard...', but it may be that the situation @PeterShor envisages is so peculiar in itself that it is hard to imagine such words being used, even though they would be right. If you wish to speak of  that situation, then it is OK to use those words. But are you sure that that is the situation?

Comment: @JermyC: lf you were a non-native speaker, you would ask the same question. If a native speaker says that X is unacceptable, you will definitely ask about the reason. This is simply the situation.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the issue. I thought this was about the use of would with unless. But it is about tenses. The only glitch I see is that I would switch the pronoun and the proper noun around. Then it sounds fine to me. Not a problem for [Education First](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/how-use-unless), either.

Comment: @PeterShor I think you have it backwards. *Unless* affords us the ability to deduce the truth in the subordinate clause based on knowing the truth of the main clause.  So if we do know she passed the exams, then we conclude she studied hard.  Knowing the main clause is true is necessary and sufficient to conclude the truth of the subordinate clause. Knowing the subordinate clause is true is necessary, but not sufficient, to conclude the main clause is true. So it is far less helpful knowing the truth about the subordinate clause. We just say *having studied hard for her exam, ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, that sentence

- ?***Unless** Ann had studied hard, she would have failed the exam.*

is not fully grammatical. OK, that happens. What makes it interesting is that, normally, *unless* means *if not*. And if you use *if ... not* instead of *unless*, everything works just fine:

- ***If** Ann had **not** studied hard, she would have failed the exam.*

But it clearly doesn't work with *unless* very well. The effect of this sentence on a native speaker is telling. The meaning is reasonable but the parsing sends up a flag. Frankly, I don't know why. It must be something about putting the negation and the *if* together in one lexical item, but why it's flagged here is very puzzling.

Comment: Hmmm. I disagree with your grammaticality judgement there. It's just difficult to find a context where it would be pragmatically ok. It's not that hard though.

Comment: Difficulty in context-finding is my definition of ungrammaticality. But if you like, I'll promote it to **?**.

Comment: @Araucaria *Unless* is more like *only if not*: [Ekaterina Vostrikova proposed](https://semanticsarchive.net/Archive/DRjNjViN/Vostrikova.pdf) that “the meaning of *unless* conditionals can be derived from the same ingredients as the meaning of *only-if-not* conditionals: a negative conditional and an exhaustifier that, like *only*, negates all of the focus alternatives for a modal claim built by substitution of the element marked with focus with other elements of the same semantic type, **but unlike *only* also asserts its prejacent.”** There’s more where that came from.

Answer (score 0):

Because we think of a hypothetical situation as not happening yet, or hard to happen and for this reason, no one can be sure whether the situation can happen or not, "unless" doesn't feel appropriate to use for describing the hypothetical situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/unless) says:

> **We don’t use unless for things that we know to be true:**
>
> *You won’t be able to get a ticket for the match unless you’re prepared to pay a lot of money for it.* (The speaker doesn’t know if
> you’re prepared to pay a lot of money for a ticket.)
>
> *I don’t know what we would have done if we hadn’t seen you.* (We did see you.)
>
> **Not**: <s>I don’t know what we would have done **unless** we’d seen you</s>.

---

I think [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/unless) also gets *unless* right in this regard by using *will not* and not *would not*. In other words, it's *not* approving it for cases that are *contrary to fact*.

**unless** (conjunction)

> CONJUNCTION You use unless to introduce the only circumstances in
> which an event you are mentioning **will not** take place or in which
> a statement you are making is not true.
>
> *Unless you are trying to lose weight to please yourself, it's going to be tough to keep your motivation level high.*

*Unless Ann had studied hard, she would have failed the exam* sounds at least odd or even wrong to many—we just don't often hear it, even though we were probably never taught an explicit rule.

Answer (score 0):

Rare does not mean ungrammatical. If we take the example to have the construction

> unless ... (had done something), ... (preterite modal auxiliary + have
> done something)

where 'preterite modal auxilialy' = *could, would, should...*

then it is possible to find examples of its use that seem quite natural.

> But, even as she prayed, she feared her prayers were vain; if Savoie
> and Cary had come out through the hall, she would already have seen
> them; and there was no stairway leading directly from their quarters
> to the ground . **Unless** they **had leaped** from a window, they
> **could not have reached** it. (Steamboat Gothic; Frances Parkinson Keyes; New York: Julian Messner, Inc.1952)
>
> **Unless** you **had seen** it you **would never have believed** hair could be so curly! It was no wonder that even strangers called the
> children "Curlytops." (Curlytops at Uncle Frank's Ranch; Garis, Howard
> Roger; 1918)
>
> And if the man lived, Conan felt certain that he was riding along the
> road somewhere ahead of him . **Unless** he **had intended** going
> into Argos he **would never have taken** the eastward road in the
> first place. (Hour of the Dragon; Robert E. Howard; 1977)
>
> The 1933 Act, permitting the creation of federal savings and loan
> associations, contained a provision respecting local taxation which
> stated in part: "... no State... shall impose any tax on such federal
> associations or their franchise, capital, reserves, surplus, loans, or
> income greater than that imposed by such authority on other similar
> local mutual or cooperative thrift and home financing institutions. "
> 48 Stat. 134 . **Unless** Congress **had recognize**d that States
> taxing national bank shares were free, in spite of 5219, to exempt
> their own savings and loan associations from local taxation, it
> **would have used** language similar or referring to 5219, as it did in other federal statutes creating different types of thrift
> institutions. (US Supreme Court 365 U.S. 467; MICHIGAN NAT. BANK v.
> MICHIGAN 1961)
>
> **Unless** Congress **had exercised** its power over interstate commerce to bring about allocation of available frequencies and to
> regulate the employment of transmission equipment the result **would
> have been** an impairment of the effective use of these facilities by
> anyone. (US Supreme Court 309 U.S. 470; FEDERAL COMMUNICATIONS COM'N
> v. SANDERS BROS. RADIO STATION 1940)
>
> **Unless** she **had fled** faster than Atalanta, William **must have been** but a
> few minutes in reaching her immediate neighborhood. ([A Dunnet
> Shepherdess - Sarah Orne Jewett Text Project](http://www.public.coe.edu/%7Etheller/soj/tqt/dun-shep.htm))
>
> **Unless** he **had taken** the senses into account, he **would not have argued** immutability from sensible mutations not being seen.  ([Galileo Galilei | Calendars - Webexhibits](http://www.webexhibits.org/calendars/year-text-Galileo.html))
>
> **Unless** he **had created** them in righteousness and true holiness, he **would** himself **have been** the author of sin, and would by this means have possessed no right either to punish them to the praise of his justice, or to save them to the praise of his mercy. ([The Wesley Center Online: Arminius' Theological Sentiments](http://wesley.nnu.edu/arminianism/the-works-of-james-arminius/volume-1/arminius-theological-sentiments/))